# Convert octal representation of a number to decimal

Tags: c++, hex

Assume one has an vector or array of N elements (N can be very large)  containing the octal representation of a non negative integer. How do I get the decimal representation of the number from this array? The code has to be really fast.

EDIT: array A of N elements contains octal representation of a non-negative integer K, i.e. each element of A belongs to the interval [0; 7] (both ends included)

Example:  A[0] = 2; A[1] = 6; A[2] = 3

Now a naive calculation would be 2*8pow0 + 6*8pow1 + 3*8pow2 = 2+ 48+ 192 = 242

I tried this but it does not seem to work for large inputs > 6K

```
//vector<int> A is the input
using namespace std;
vector<int>::iterator it = A.begin();

unsigned int k = 0;
unsigned int x = 0;
while(it < A.end()){
   x = x | (*it<<3*k);
   k++;
   it++;
}
```

I am also having problems converting a hexadecimal string to its decimal representation? Is this the correct way to do this in C++:
//Assume S to be your input string containing a hex representation 
//like F23

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << S;
ss >> x;
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the octal representation of a non negative integer"? Do you have a distinct type for that?

Comment: This can probably be considered a duplicate for any number of questions that come up in a search for ["base conversion"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=base+conversion).

Comment: @FredOverflow I think the intention is that the vector contains a single number, each cell containing a digit (base 8). What I'm struggling with is whether an interviewer would expect you to pull out of your sleeve an arbitrary-precision integer library.

Comment: @Oli : I want to know what is wrong with my code and If we can do it better..

Comment: @user: To find out what's wrong with your code, I suggest stepping through it in a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
template<typename Iter>
int read_octal(Iter begin, Iter end)
{
    int x = 0;
    int f = 1;
    for (; begin != end; ++begin)
    {
        x += *begin * f;
        f *= 8;
    }
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    int test[] = {2, 6, 3};
    int result = read_octal(test + 0, test + 3);
    std::cout << result << '\n';
}
```

> I tried this but it does not seem to work for large inputs > 6K

What exactly do you mean by 6k? An int usually has 32 bits, and an octal digit has 3 bits. Thus, you cannot have more than 10 elements in your range, otherwise x will overflow.

> I am also having problems converting a hexadecimal string to its decimal representation?

Well, you could always write a function to parse a string in hex format yourself:

```
int parse_hex(const char* p)
{
    int x = 0;
    for (; *p; ++p)
    {
        x = x * 16 + digit_value(*p);
    }
    return x;
}
```

With the most portable version of `digit_value` being:

```
int digit_value(char c)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case '0': return 0;
        case '1': return 1;
        case '2': return 2;
        case '3': return 3;
        case '4': return 4;
        case '5': return 5;
        case '6': return 6;
        case '7': return 7;
        case '8': return 8;
        case '9': return 9;
        case 'A': 
        case 'a': return 10;
        case 'B': 
        case 'b': return 11;
        case 'C': 
        case 'c': return 12;
        case 'D': 
        case 'd': return 13;
        case 'E': 
        case 'e': return 14;
        case 'F': 
        case 'f': return 15;
    }
}
```

Comment: would your code for octal work for very large input arrays (10,000,000 elements) ?

Comment: @user: Of course not: "An int usually has 32 bits, and an octal digit has 3 bits. Thus, you cannot have more than 10 elements in your range, otherwise x will overflow."

Comment: I see. Can I contact you offline and send you the exact problem description? i think either I have not understood the problem clearly or I am unable to express it.It will be a great help. Or maybe you can write to me at aquarian.thunder@gmail.com. thanks!

Comment: @user: All I can tell you is that you obviously cannot just parse the value into an int. I don't have any more insights into the problem. Should I stumble upon a solution, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Arbitray precision octal to decimal conversion is rather annoying because there is no way to localize the computation. In other words a change in the most significant digit of the octal number will change even the least significant digit in the decimal representation.

That said I think I would convert the octal number to a say base-1000000000 number and then I'd print that (this is instead a trivial problem, each base-1000000000 digit just maps trivially to 9 base-10 digits).

The conversion to base-1000000000 is simple because you only need to support incrementing and multiplying by two (just consider the input as binary with three bits for each octal digit).

## EDIT

I tried to implement it in C++ and this is the resulting code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    // Base 100,000,000 accumulator
    // Initialized with one digit = 0
    std::vector<unsigned> big(1);
    const unsigned DIGIT = 100000000;

    for (int c=getchar(); c >= '0' && c <= '7'; c=getchar()) {
        // Multiply accumulator by 8 and add in incoming digit
        int carry = c - '0';
        for (int i=0,n=big.size(); i<n; i++) {
            unsigned x = big[i] * 8 + carry;
            carry = x / DIGIT;
            big[i] = x - carry * DIGIT;
        }
        if (carry) big.push_back(carry);
    }

    // Output result in decimal
    printf("%i", big.back());
    for (int i=int(big.size())-2; i>=0; i--) {
        printf("%08i", big[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

On my PC the time to convert an 80,000 digit octal number to decimal (resulting in 72246 digits) is about 1.2 seconds. Doing the same using python eval/str the time is about 3 seconds. The number used was `"01234567" * 10000`.

The code above uses 100,000,000 as base so that it can process one digit (3 bits) at a time with 32-bit arithmetic not overflowing with the intermediate results. I tried also using 64 bit integers or the 53 bit integer part of a `double` but the code was running always slower than in this case (one reason is probably the division in the inner loop that can be converted to a multiplication in the 32 bit case).

This is still a simple O(n^2) implementation that would take ages to convert a 10,000,000-digits octal number.